# How do I sort parent documents in MongoDb using a value from a child array?

Tags: mongodb

We have a document that contains an array holding a varying number of attributes that may or may not exist per document.

For example:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("570ca1a61992d1f7603b997e"), 
    "Name" : "Product 1", 
    "LastUpdated" : {
        "DateTime" : ISODate("2016-04-12T07:20:07.041+0000"), 
        "Ticks" : NumberLong(635960424070414818)
    }, 
    "Attributes" : [
        "ProductType:Shirt", 
        "Colour:Red", 
        "Year:2016", 
        "Gender:Boys"
    ]
}
```

We currently sort by top level properties but now need to sort by the attributes such as Year.

How can we achieve this without having to modify the document structure we have currently? It is possible without aggregation?

I have tried using the aggregation framework to unwind the attributes, match the relevant attribute and then sort which works but then we are left with a document that only contains the matching attribute from the unwind, not the full array. I'm not sure if there is a way to get the full document after an unwind or could we use the resulting matching document ids in another match?

```
db.Product.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: {
      "Attributes" : "Colour:Red"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$Attributes"
    },
    {
      $match: {
      "Attributes" : /^Year:/
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
      "Attributes" : -1
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

Comment: Your document is not a valid JSON document. Is "Attributes" an array of subdocuments?

Comment: @user3100115 Attributes is an array of strings. The document looks fine to me, what is wrong with it?

Comment: The document look a little odd to me, why not use an array of embedded document as "Attributes"? You are "simulating" this using the ":" notation. I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but I really think you should change the document structure

Comment: @RafaelTeles The structure was chosen to support faceted search so we could group and count the number of products matching each attribute.

Comment: @rrrr sorry didn't see the double quote  `"` but it's weird

Comment: I have to agree with @RafaelTeles I can't see any valid reason to use such structure. You should definitely consider to change your document structure and make "Attributes" an array of sub-documents or sub-documents if you don't have duplicates.

Comment: @user3100115 As mentioned above this was chosen to allow grouping and counting for use in a faceted search where the number of attributes is unknown.